# Puerto Rico Land Use Land Cover GIS Data

Tags: geospatial

I am looking for Puerto Rico Land Use Land Cover GIS data that has residential/commercial office/commercial retail classifications. I have not been able to find anything

Answer (score 1):

The NOAA Office for Coastal Management publishes C-CAP regional land use land cover data for Puerto Rico.  See this link:  https://coast.noaa.gov/digitalcoast/data/ccapregional.html